# get selected data form grouped collection select

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, select, dynamic

I want to get my selected link id to make something like that : 
[image]

I am in the links#admin view
my create button is working,
now i have one grouped collection to select my link :

```
<%= link_to 'add link', 
    new_link_path, 
    class: "add-link btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm article__add-btn" 
%>
```

And i want to edit or remove this link so i need to get the id :

exemple for remove ( I use Link.last for the test but i need the selected value :

```
  <%= link_to "remove", 
      link_path(Link.last), 
      class: "btn-delete-custom btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm ", 
      data: {:confirm => "sure?"}, 
      method: :delete 
  %>
```

I want also display dynamically if that possible the form with the selected link values

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

There is my controler

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class LinksController < ApplicationController

    def index

      end

      def create
        @link = Link.new(link_params)
        if @link.save
          flash[:notice] = "Votre Lien a été créé !"
        else
          flash.now[:alert] = "Erreur lors la création du lien"
        end
        redirect_to root_path
      end

      def destroy
        @link = Link.find(params[:id])

        if @link.destroy
          flash[:notice] = "Le lien a bien été supprimé"
          redirect_to root_path
        else
          flash[:alert] = "Erreur lors de la suppression du lien"
          redirect_to root_path
        end
      end

    def admin
    end

    private

    def link_params
      params.require(:link).permit(:name, :url, :category_id)
    end

    def find_link
      @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Comment: in which view are you ? links#create ? how do you populate the dropdown "Selection Link" ? maybe add some code from the controller

Comment: @sovalina i am in the links#admin view code updated , i put the controler

Comment: Can you please add also the code for the grouped collection from which you select your link?